# Convertir un xml node en string

Tags: c#

Hola a todos tengo la siguiente parte de un código:

```
XmlNode lDatos = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago");
```

Mi duda es:
Hay forma de poder utilitzar lDatos?

Puedo ver si no es null.
Pero me gustaria poder hacer algo así:

```
if(lDatos.equals("respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago").....
```

Pero no se como puedo utilizar ese texto..

El xml es así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago lang="ESP">
```

Por lo que no sé como puedo extraerlo. Sé que con el `xDoc.SelectSingleNode` selecciono que sea al menos con ese nombre. Pero luego quiero poder compararlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hay forma de poder utilitzar lDatos***:

> Si, siempre y cuando no sea nulo. [Te dejo la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode?view=netframework-4.8).

***Puedo ver si no es null***:

> Si, solo debes hacer `if(lDatos != null)`.

***Pero me gustaria poder hacer algo así***: `if(lDatos.equals("respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago")`

> Para eso primero validas que no sea nulo y luego utilzas la propiedad `Name`. [Te dejo la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.name?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_Name).

---

Te dejo un ejemplo, para que lo revises:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"yes\"?><respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago lang=\"ESP\"></respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago>");

        XmlNode elem = doc.SelectSingleNode("respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago");

        if(elem != null && elem.Name == "respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago") {
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + elem.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo que dejo esta todo lo que preguntas, incluyendo la verificacion del nombre de la etiqueta `respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago`.

Comment: lo pruebo muchas gracias!! <3

Comment: Recuerda revisar los enlace de la documentacion, en ellos encontraras mas informacion, como por ejemplo: como selecionar informacion del innerText, outerText o innerXml y otras propiedades mas.

Comment: la duda que tengo es, al estar el elem lleno, eso significa basicamente que ha encontrado la respuesta no? Es decir podria hacer algo así :     XmlNode lDatos = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("respuestaCancAvisoFaltaPago");

Si no esta null es por que ha encontrado algo no?

Comment: Estas en lo correcto.

Comment: muchas gracias!!! ahora me queda más claro! ^^